# Как сделать вывод только одной единицы времени?

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot, datetime

Оператор `else` выводит сообщения с оставшимся временем кулдауна, но выводит из любой переменной(`hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`) одни и те же данные - `часы:минуты:секунды`. Как сделать, чтобы единицы времени выводились в порядке ч`асы:минут:cекунды`, но только разными переменными, то есть часы - `hours`, минуты - `minutes`, секунды - `seconds` и чтобы в итоге получилось что-то типа `Осталось n часов n минут n секунд`?

```py
import telebot
import sqlite3
import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

sql = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
conn = sql.cursor()


@bot.message_handler(commands=["go"])
def go(message):
    last_command_use_time = \
    conn.execute('SELECT get_card_cd FROM users WHERE user_id={}'.format(message.chat.id)).fetchone()[0]
    x = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_command_use_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    seconds = (datetime.datetime.now() - x).seconds
    print(seconds)
    print(datetime.datetime.minute)

    if not last_command_use_time or (datetime.datetime.now() - x).seconds / 14400 > 1:
        # Если кнопка не нажималась или с прошлого запуска команды прошёл час
        conn.execute('UPDATE users SET get_card_cd=? WHERE user_id=?', (datetime.datetime.now(), message.chat.id))
        sql.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нужное сообщение...')
    else:
        # Если же час ещё не прошёл
        seconds = (x - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds - 72000
        minutes = datetime.timedelta(minutes=seconds/60)
        hours = datetime.timedelta(hours=seconds/3600)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Осталось подождать {} времени'.format(hours))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильный перевод времени. используйте эту функцию:

```
def convert(seconds):
    min_, sec = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hour, min_ = divmod(min_, 60)
    day=0
    if hour>=24:
        day=hour//24
        hour=hour%24
    if day!=0:
        day=str(day)+' дней,'
    else:
        day=''
    if hour!=0:
        hour=str(hour)+' часов,'
    else:
        hour=''
    if min!=0:
        min_=str(min_)+' минут и'
    else:
        min_=''

    return f'{day} {hour} {min_} {sec} секунд.'
```

Вот что будет в блоке `else`:

```
seconds = (x - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds - 72000
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Осталось подождать {}'.format(convert(seconds)))
```

**Кстати, последнюю строку можете заменить просто на:**

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Осталось подождать {convert(seconds)}')
```

Comment: Вывод в чате - *Осталось подождать 3.1241666666666665:187.45:11247 времени*

Код:
    else:
        seconds_1 = (x - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds - 72000
        seconds = seconds = seconds_1
        minutes = minutes = seconds_1 / 60
        hours = hours = seconds_1 / 3600
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Осталось подождать {}:{}:{} времени'.format(hours, minutes, seconds))

Comment: 1. Почему `hours=hours=...`? Просто `hours=...`. 2. У вас неверно создана функция, сейчас поправлю ответ

Comment: а, с hours = hours моя ошибка

Comment: не очень понимаю как вместить эту функцию в мой код и подстроить else под нее

Comment: Просто встройте её где-нибудь в начале кода, вне функции.

Comment: А в `else` вставьте то, что у меня после троеточия

Comment: if day != 0:
       ^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'day' where it is not associated with a value

Comment: Прошу прощения, поправил

Comment: Теперь должно работать, проверьте

Comment: все заработало, спасибо большое вам!

Comment: Не за что:) Был рад помочь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149028/discussion-between---and-panickx).